# AWS WAF Log Partition Projection: Partitions not in metastore

Tags: amazon-athena, amazon-waf

Im trying to set up a table in Athena with partition projection.
My logs are in the format `s3://bucket/folder/year/month/day/hour` and then a json file inside that.

I have tried creating the table with partition projection as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `waf_logs_webacl1`(
  `timestamp` bigint,
  `formatversion` int,
  `webaclid` string,
  `terminatingruleid` string,
  `terminatingruletype` string,
  `action` string,
  `terminatingrulematchdetails` array<
                                  struct<
                                    conditiontype:string,
                                    location:string,
                                    matcheddata:array<string>
                                        >
                                     >,
  `httpsourcename` string,
  `httpsourceid` string,
  `rulegrouplist` array<
                     struct<
                        rulegroupid:string,
                        terminatingrule:struct<
                           ruleid:string,
                           action:string,
                           rulematchdetails:string
                                               >,
                        nonterminatingmatchingrules:array<
                                                       struct<
                                                          ruleid:string,
                                                          action:string,
                                                          rulematchdetails:array<
                                                               struct<
                                                                  conditiontype:string,
                                                                  location:string,
                                                                  matcheddata:array<string>
                                                                     >
                                                                  >
                                                               >
                                                            >,
                        excludedrules:array<
                                         struct<
                                            ruleid:string,
                                            exclusiontype:string
                                               >
                                            >
                           >
                       >,
  `ratebasedrulelist` array<
                        struct<
                          ratebasedruleid:string,
                          limitkey:string,
                          maxrateallowed:int
                              >
                           >,
  `nonterminatingmatchingrules` array<
                                  struct<
                                    ruleid:string,
                                    action:string
                                        >
                                     >,
  `requestheadersinserted` string,
  `responsecodesent` string,
  `httprequest` struct<
                      clientip:string,
                      country:string,
                      headers:array<
                                struct<
                                  name:string,
                                  value:string
                                      >
                                   >,
                      uri:string,
                      args:string,
                      httpversion:string,
                      httpmethod:string,
                      requestid:string
                      >,
  `labels` array<
             struct<
               name:string
                   >
                  >
)
PARTITIONED BY
(
 day STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://bucket/folder/'
TBLPROPERTIES
(
 "projection.enabled" = "true",
 "projection.day.type" = "date",
 "projection.day.range" = "2021/01/01,NOW",
 "projection.day.format" = "yyyy/MM/dd/HH",
 "projection.day.interval" = "1",
 "projection.day.interval.unit" = "YEARS",
 "storage.location.template" = "s3://bucket/folder/${year}/${month}/${day}/${hour}/"
)
```

It gets created successfully but when I load all the partitions in it gives me the error

```
Partitions not in metastore:    waf_logs_webacl1:2021/05/16/23  waf_logs_webacl1:2021/05/17/00  waf_logs_webacl1:2021/05/17/01  waf_logs_webacl1:2021/05/17/02  waf_logs_webacl1:2021/05/17/03 etc
```

I have also tried with the storage.location.template being `s3://bucket/folder/` and `s3://bucket/folder/${year}/` and get the same error when loading partitions. Please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use partition projection you don't need to load partitions, the partitions will be found at query execution time.

The problem with your table is that you have one partition key, `day`, but you say to Athena that the data is stored in a directory structure containing `/${year}/${month}/${day}/${hour}/`, i.e. four partition keys.

Either you need to create the table with all four partition keys and configure partition projection for them (e.g. `projection.year.type`, etc.) or you need to remove the undefined keys from the storage location template.

I think the right course of action is the former, since that's how the data is organized. There is an example in the Athena docs that you should be able to use as a starting point here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-kinesis-firehose-example.html *(edit: this page has been removed from the documentation and there is no updated version)*

Comment: I tried the way from the doc you linked, which looks like what I want but I get this error when querying it:

```INVALID_TABLE_PROPERTY: Table waf_logs.waf_logs_webacl1 is configured for partition projection, but the following partition columns are missing projection configuration: [datehour] (table waf_logs.waf_logs_webacl1)```

Also looked into when you say configure partition projection for each of the four partition keys. Do I add year,month,day,hour ato PARTITIONED BY and then inside TBLPROPERTIES do I add projection.year.type etc inside the brackets?

Comment: You need to have the same partition keys in `PARTITIONED BY` as in the `storage.location.template` property, and each also needs at least a `projection.NAME.type` property (and depending on the type one or more properties). If your error says there is missing configuration for `datehour` you have that in `PARTITIONED BY` but at least no `projection.datehour.type` property.